# Django: best way to define a form to insert long texts?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with Django1.8 and Python 2.7.+

I want to define a form that has text field where the user can insert a text as long as he needs to.

The first thing that I tried was defining a `forms.TextField`, but it turns out `TextField` only exists under `models`, not under `forms`.

This is how I have defined it:

```
selected_services = forms.CharField(label="Selected_services *",
                                    max_length=999999999,
                                    widget=forms.Textarea())
```

But the `max_length=999999999,` looks terrible.

What would be a more elegant way of defining a form field to store very long texts?

Comment: The *"how it looks"* part of the form is mostly `html` and `css`, so you might wanna consider retagging the question.

Comment: @Adelin what I meant was that the piece of code with the arbitrary "999999" hardcoded didn't seem very elegant to me.

Comment: right - i understand now. I've attempted an answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should remain that way:

```
selected_services = forms.CharField(label="Selected_services *",
                                widget=forms.Textarea())
```

Defining the TextArea widget becomes a TextField and the max_length attribute is not required

Answer (score 2):

Only `models.CharField` requires `max_length`. You can remove it from your `forms.CharField`.

Apart from that your current code looks fine. The `TextArea` is the right widget to use.

Answer (score 1):

`max_length` property doesn't appear to have an upper limit.

I've checked the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#TextField) and [this forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/)

So you might wanna try using `sys.maxint` (python 2) or `sys.maxsize` (python 3) instead of arbitrary number.